# Struts2 jQuery Autocompleter with select box

Tags: java, json, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery

I've used the Struts2 jQuery `autocompleter` for my Struts 2 application.

Here is my code:

**JSP:**

```
 <s:form id="frm_demo" theme="simple" action="ManagersAutoCompleter1">
        <s:url var="remoteurl" action="test" />
    <sj:autocompleter href="%{remoteurl}" id="echo3" name="echo"
        list="itemList" listKey="id" listValue="name" emptyOption="true"
        headerKey="-1" headerValue="Please Select a Language" selectBox="true" />

        <s:submit value="submit" />
    </s:form>
```

**`Struts.xml`:**

```
<action name="test" class="test.TestAction" method="populate">
  <result type="json">
  </result>
</action>
```

**Action Class:**

```
 public String populate() throws Exception {

        itemList = new ArrayList<ListValue>();
        itemList.add(new ListValue("Php", "Php"));
        itemList.add(new ListValue("Java", "Java"));
        itemList.add(new ListValue("Mysl", "Mysl"));
        return SUCCESS;
    } //getter setter for itemList
```

**List Class:**

```
public class ListValue {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public ListValue(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    } //getter setter methods
```

But this Struts2 jQuery `autocompleter` is not working. It doesn't populate any values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do this one**

```
<s:url id="remoteurl" action="test"/>
<sj:select 
     id="customersjsonlstid" 
     name="echo"
     label="Handle a List"
     href="%{remoteurl}" 
     list="itemList"
     listValue="name" 
     listKey="id" 
     autocomplete="true"  
     loadMinimumCount="2" 
     id="echo3"/>
```

**Instead of this**:

```
<sj:autocompleter href="%{remoteurl}" id="echo3" name="echo"
list="itemList" listKey="id" listValue="name" emptyOption="true"
headerKey="-1" headerValue="Please Select a Language" selectBox="true" />
```

And make sure you are returning the list from your action class.
To check this, do it  with your IDE debugger or System.out.print etc.

```
ex...


    -------------
    ------------
    itemList.add(new ListValue("Mysl", "Mysl") );
    System.out.println("Size of my list="+itemList.size());
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

And also you should define getter & setters in your action class

```
private List itemList; 
    public List getItemList() {
    return itemList;
} 

public void setItemList(List itemList) {
    this.itemList = itemList;
}
```

Comment: awesome..awesome it works using json!!!, actually I'm quite new on JQuery, really thanks for your support

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
<sj:autocompleter href="%{remoteurl}" id="lst" name="lst"
    list="itemList" listValue="name" listKey="id" selectBox="true" />
```

You are feeding the autocompleter with a Map, not with an custom object built by yourself.

An [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) does not have any `name` nor `id` fields, instead it have `key`s and `value`s fields.

Start by changing that and see if it works:

```
<sj:autocompleter href="%{remoteurl}" id="lst" name="lst"
    list="itemList" listValue="value" listKey="key" selectBox="true" />
```

Comment: Ok thank you.I have edited my question. Now I am replace Map  with Simple List. But It still Doesn't work. can u plz help me?

Answer (score 1):

You have typed wrong attribute that is not referenced.

> ```
> <s:url id="remoteurl" action="test" />
> ```

should be

```
 <s:url var="remoteurl" action="test" />
```

Use the list item bean class

```
public class ListValue {
  private String id;
  private String name;
...
}

public String populate() throws Exception {
  itemList.add(new ListValue("Php", "Php"));
  itemList.add(new ListValue("Java","Java") );
  itemList.add(new ListValue("Mysl", "Mysl") );
  return SUCCESS;
}
```

assumed that constructor and mutators have been added.

Comment: The Struts2-Jquery autocompleter doesn't populate any values and it shows just like a text box.it does not have a dropdown functionalites.i used struts2-jquery-tree-plugin-3.5.0.jar and struts2-json-plugin-2.3.7.jar plugins.

Comment: did you included json-plugin?

Comment: But your list item doesn't have id, nor name attributes.

Comment: I've used LabelValueBean for that purposes to render lists.

Comment: LabelValueBean you could find in Apache projects. Check the edit.

Comment: can You please check my code? .I have edited as you said,but still its not working.

Comment: It doesn't throw any exceptions. 
The Struts2-Jquery autocompleter doesn't populate any values and it shows just like a text box.it does not have a dropdown icon.