# Struts2 JQuery Plugin AutoCompleter does not work when selectBox="true" attribute is added

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-plugins, struts2, struts2-jquery-plugin

Works (Loads the list fine):

```
<s:url id="countrylist" action="lstcountryaction" />
<sj:autocompleter list="lstcountry"
    listKey="idcountry" listValue="countryname" label="Country"
    href="%{countrylist}" name="idcountry" />
```

Doesn't work (Nothing is loaded. No call is made to the action) :

```
<s:url id="countrylist" action="lstcountryaction" />
<sj:autocompleter selectBox="true" list="lstcountry"
    listKey="idcountry" listValue="countryname" label="Country"
    href="%{countrylist}" name="idcountry" />
```

Only difference is that the `selectBox` attribute is added. What am I missing? I am using Struts 2.3.15 and Struts2 JQuery Plugin 3.6.1 (which are both fairly recent).

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Struts2 jQuery [`<sj:autocompleter>`](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/wiki/AutocompleterTag) widget with the `selectBox=true` enabled to be able to work correctly shouldn't load data remotely.  In other words the attribute `href="%{countrylist}"` is a culprit of the select box is not working. These two attributes are mutually exclusive. You have to choose between two options either you use a `autocompleter` as input box with remote data or as select box but without loading data remotely, because it's loaded from the `valueStack` as a normal `select` tag.

You can supplement a select box with `selectBoxIcon="true"` to make the widget appear smoothly or use a corresponding jQuery theme in the header tag.

Try it

```xml
<sj:autocompleter selectBox="true" selectBoxIcon="true" list="lstcountry"
    listKey="idcountry" listValue="countryname" label="Country"
    name="idcountry" />
```

An [example](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/wiki/AutocompleterTag#autocompleter-as-a-select-box) from the struts2 jQuery plugin wiki page.

Answer (score 2):

+1 because I see you've [already posted on the relative Google Group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/struts2-jquery/s0F9_oFYLRQ/t97PzO4xBlgJ)... but, if the things are not changed meanwhile, according to [this (pretty old, but still open JIRA) comment](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/issues/detail?id=488#c4) by the plugin author:

> **The autocompleter with selectBox is working with an static list. In
>   your use case you should use the `<sj:select />` tag with
>   autocomplete="true" instead.**
>
> ```
> <s:url id="remoteurl" action="jsonsample"/> 
> <sj:select
>          href="%{remoteurl}"
>          autocomplete="true"
>          id="echo3"
>          name="echo"
>          list="languageObjList"
>          listKey="myKey"
>          listValue="myValue"
>          emptyOption="true"
>          headerKey="-1"
>          headerValue="Please Select a Language"/>
> ```

Then an `<sj:select />` with both `emptyOption` and `autocomplete` set to `true` could be the replacement for the dynamic selectbox `<sj:autocompleter />` you are looking for.

Feel free to run [this example too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14186003/1654265), that appears to work out of the box.